# Disable remove pemission on linux

Tags: linux, ftp, fedora

I have made a ftp directory I want that virtual users can create and update folders and files but they can not delete them. how do I suppose to do that? I have created this ftp by vsftp in fedora 16 platform.

Thank you,

Comment: So users can "modify" files to zero length, but they cant delete them?  I think the write bit authorizes both file modification and unlinking - and it can't be seperated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can instruct `vsftpd` to [no longer honor the `DELE` and `RMD` commands](http://flukylogs.blogspot.com/2012/01/vsftpd-behind-routerfirewall.html):

```
# Disable delete commands
cmds_denied=DELE,RMD
```

Though [user1131467's concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916634/disable-remove-pemission-on-linux#comment12655769_9916634) still stands -- if the users can modify files, they can *truncate* the files or overwrite them with garbage. (Well, the `chattr(1)` *append only* attribute can enforce append-only behavior, but this is far from an ideal solution.)

Comment: +1 Other FTP daemons have similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer in this page:
http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

look for the value "file_open_mode" to set the umask for the uploded files to the desired value to prevent the write permission.

the default value is 0666, in your case it may be 0440. (do not forget the leading 0).

Comment: you might also need to do something to prevent them from using chmod.